# Pass value from parent to child component with React

Tags: reactjs

I trying to display the rating of a query in my React App. But I'm not sure if I understand how to handle the state.

This is my query component:

```
import React, { Component, useRef, useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { render } from 'react-dom';
import InputSearchLandlord from './search'
import './style.css'
import SimpleRating from '../components/star_display'
import ReactStars from 'react-rating-stars-component'
import './style.css'

    
const HandleSearch = () => {
    const [ratingValue, setRating] = useState(0)
    const [name, searcName] = useState("")

    const nameForm = useRef(null)

    const average = arr => arr.reduce( ( p, c ) => p + c, 0 ) / arr.length;
    const ratings = []
    const displayComment = async() => {
        try {
            const form = nameForm.current
            const name = form['name'].value
            searchName(name)
            const response = await fetch(`localhost`)
            const jsonData = await response.json()
            getComments(jsonData)
            comments.forEach(e => {
                console.log(e.rating)
                ratings.push(e.rating)
            })
            const rating = average(ratings) //Avg of all rating associated with the search 
            console.log(rating)             //Should be pass to Rating component
            setRating(rating)
        } catch (error) {
            console.log(error.message)
        }
    }


    return(
        <div className="container">
        <div className="form-group">
        <h1 className="text-center mt-5">SEARCH</h1>
            <form ref={nameForm} className="mt-5">
                <InputSearch name={'name'}/>
                <div className="d-flex justify-content-center">
                    <button type="submit" className="d-flex btn btn-primary" onClick={displayComment}>Search</button>
                </div>
            </form>
            <div>
            <div className='container'>
                <h1>{name}</h1>
                <SimpleRating data={ratingValue}
                />
            </div>
            <div className='container'>
                {comments.map(comment => (
                    <div className="commentSection">
                         <a>
                            {comment.problem}
                        </a><br/>
                        <a>
                                Posted on : {comment.date}
                        </a>
                    </div>
                ))}
            </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        </div>
    )
}

export default HandleSearch;
```

And this is my Rating component:

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { render } from 'react-dom';
import ReactStars from 'react-rating-stars-component'
import './style.css'
import HandleSearch from '../pages/handleSearch'


export default function SimpleRating(rating) {

  const [ratingValue, setRating] = useState(0)

  const options = {
    value: ratingValue, //Should use the value from the Search component
    a11y: true,
    isHalf: true,
    edit: false,
  };

  console.log(options.value)

  if (options.value == 0) return null //if rating value = 0 doesn't display the component

  return (
    <div className="starComponent">
      <ReactStars {...options}/>
    </div>
  );
}
```

So I trying to pass the value computed in the Search component to the Rating component. Before any query is made with the Search component, the value should be 0 and hidden.

What am I missing ?

Comment: Whats going on with this line ```const response = await fetch(`localhost`)``` I dont think you are actually getting anything back since you are just pointing to localhost

Answer (score 0):

Its to do with your props. In your parent component you create a prop called data so in your rating component you need to extract that value from props

```js
//  HandleSearch Component
<SimpleRating data={ratingValue}

export default function SimpleRating(props) {
  const { data } = props
  // You can also just say props.data 

  ... rest of your component
}
```

Currently you are actually defining the props in your SimpleRating component but you are calling them rating (it doesn't actually matter what you call it but commonly its called props) and that is an object that contains all of the props that you pass into that component.

Comment: So I tried this solution which brought me closer to my goal. However, it looks like my state in the Search component isn't updating properly. It stays at 0.

Comment: Then the issue is within your displayComment function. If its returning 0 then it means the state isnt changing